# Dynamic data binding not working Angular Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome-extension, data-binding

Data is not binding on Angular 6 when running as Chrome Extension.
Below is my code:

**app.component.ts**

```
constructor(){
    chrome.tabs.query({
      currentWindow: true,
      active: true
    }, function(tabs) {
    console.log(tabs[0]);
    if (tabs.length > 0) {
      if (tabs[0].url !== undefined && tabs[0].url !== null && tabs[0].url !== '') {
        this.tabId = tabs[0].id;  
        this.tabURL = tabs[0].url;
        console.log("url1"+this.tabURL);
        this.tabTitle = tabs[0].title;
        this.favIconUrl = tabs[0].favIconUrl;
      }
    }
    });
  }
```

**app.component.html**

```
   <p>Running on {{tabURL}}</p>
```

Data object we are getting and the lines are executed but data binding not reflected on the UI

*Later I have noticed that when I trigger some other button click events, the UI gets updated*

Comment: Callbacks in chrome extensions API are invoked asynchronously so I guess you need to force an update of your Angular app manually at the end of this callback.

Comment: manually means ? @wOxxOm , Actually I could get the data binding on button trigger event but not in constructor or ngOnInit